# can't use terminal from error in .bash_profile

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I added some things to my .bash_profile on my Mac OS X and they give an error. Here is my entire log of text when I start a terminal now:

```
Last login: Thu Oct 25 23:10:03 on ttys000
dirname: illegal option -- b
usage: dirname path
-bash: /bin/naoqi-bin: No such file or directory
-bash: exec: /bin/naoqi-bin: cannot execute: No such file or directory

[Process completed]
```

The problem is that since "Process completed", I can't use terminal. How do I access .bash_profile (I can't find out how from the finder), or how do I run terminal normally again so I can get that out of the .bash_profile file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message on Terminal launch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246238/error-message-on-terminal-launch)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to restore .bash\_profile on a mac? None of my unix terminal are working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067625/how-to-restore-bash-profile-on-a-mac-none-of-my-unix-terminal-are-working)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Open `Terminal`, and go to `File (or Shell) -> New Command`. Type in `open -e .profile` (or substitute some other file instead of `.profile`), and hit Run. That should open TextEdit with the file you want to fix; you can remove the offending lines there.

Answer (score 7):

For completeness, here's another way: open TextEdit (or your favorite GUI text editor). In the  open dialog, press <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Period</kbd>, and it'll display (and let you open) invisible files such as .profile. Remove the offending lines, save, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Bash with all startup scripts disabled to get around problems with startup scripts: choose **Shell > New Command** and run `bash --noprofile`.

See the Bash man page for more information about the Bash command-line options and startup files: x-man-page://1/bash

Also note that you can lookup and view man pages in Terminal even when your shell isn't working, by clicking on the Help menu and entering a topic in the search field. Terminal will display matching man pages. Choose one from the Help menu to view it in a new window. You can also open an `x-man-page:` scheme URL from any application.

Answer (score 0):

I could not open it with:

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

But when I entered

```
sudo open ~/.bash_profile
```

It worked and I was able to open the file!

Comment: You absolutely should not need `sudo` to open your `.bash_profile` in the first place; it _needs_ to be owned by yourself.