# Basic command lines on Mac terminal not working

Tags: macos, shell

I changed the bash profile while trying to install mongodb and none of my command lines are working on terminal.  I read online that I need to fix the $PATH but I can't even access it when none of my commands are working.

Help?

Comment: `$ PATH=$PATH:/new/dir/to/add`

Comment: Edit your .profile with a text editor?

Comment: how do i access the .profile from text editor. where is it located?

Comment: i did nano .bash_profile and it doesn't work.  Probably because my terminal is screwed up by $PATH

Comment: You can also try `/usr/bin/nano .bash_profile` to bypass path lookup.

Answer (score 22):

Mistakenly I also ran into same problem where to resolve this I had to reset my PATH variable to basic settings as below :

**`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin"`**

Once you set PATH variable now you can open the **.bash_profile file in same terminal session only** and make changes accordingly. This will resolve your problem.

Comment: Once I run this command it works fine. But after close the terminal & reopen the terminal the same issue exists. Could you please help with the permanent solution.

Comment: @Pawan as I mentioned once you set your PATH variable using above cmd then open **.bash_profile** file in _same terminal session_ and add your other changes like `export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH` . Even you can add try setting PATH variable also but keep that as first line in your `.bash_profile` file. Also, make sure your .bash_profile file is at user path i.e /Users/Pawan

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I have the same issue but I don't understand your answer. I have managed to: export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin". But what do I do now? You mentioned to open .bash_profile but how do I do this? I want to reset my path to its original state- I am working on a Mac

Comment: Go to home path (type cd hit enter) `/Users/patrick` and open .bash_profile like `vi .bash_profile` and then paste the PATH variable value there or any env which you wanted to append in current PATH then save the file.

Answer (score 7):

Ok I found the answer from here:

"Open Terminal, and go to File (or Shell) -> New Command. Type in `open -e .profile` (or substitute some other file instead of `.profile`), and hit Run. That should open TextEdit with the file you want to fix; you can remove the offending lines there."

in my case i typed in nano .bash_profile and that allowed me to edit my bash profile and fix the issue.

[can't use terminal from error in .bash_profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081058/cant-use-terminal-from-error-in-bash-profile)

Comment: That should be the selected answer!

Comment: Hi guys, I am having the same issue as per above, but I don't quite understand how to fix it even with the given answers above. When I run pip or other modules that previously worked, I get a zsh: command not found error. how can I reset my PATH to its original state?

Comment: When I follow this answer, I get a file that says: The file /Users/patrickchong/.profile does not exist.

[Process completed]

Answer (score 2):

Run this in terminal:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```