# Bash error when opening terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

I recently installed Ruby on my mac using this following command:

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build
```

I was then instructed to enter this command to add rbenv to bash so it loads every time the terminal is open:

```
# Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now, everytime I open the terminal I get this error:

```
Last login: Sun Sep  6 17:30:09 on ttys000
-bash: /Users/pw/.bash_profile: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `source'
-bash: /Users/pw/.bash_profile: line 1: `if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi source /Users/pw/.bash_profile'
```

Any ideas to how I can stop this error from showing?

Thanks

Comment: The line `source ~/.bash_profile` should not be in your `~/.bash_profile`. Use TextEdit to open it and remove that line.

Comment: Failing that, please click `edit` under your question and paste in the entire contents of your `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: The part of line `source ~/.bash_profile` that is. You seem to have combined the two lines of directions into a single line in your `.bash_profile` file.

Comment: More generally, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246238/error-message-on-terminal-launch

Answer (score 2):

There should be a single line at the bottom of your `~/.bash_profile` that says:

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

That's all. No mention of `source anything`.